# Payment APIs without server-side requirements

Tags: angularjs, api, payment, stripe-payments, javascript-framework

Are there any Payment APIs, preferably in Javascript/Angular that can be directly used on the client side, and thus require no server side implementation?

The best example is Stripe. It both requires setting up the client side (Checkout and retrieval of StripeToken) and then actually processing the payment on the server (Charge).

Comment: Probably not since you would have to expose your account keys in the browser. Using Stripe example, the public key can't cause any account damage, it simply allows creating a token that is then used in conjunction with secret server side key to actually process a charge

Comment: You can checkout commencepayments.com (my side project), it allows you to create customers, charges, subscriptions client side on top of Stripe -- right now it just uses a custom button but no reason why it couldn't support direct api calls. You wouldn't necessarily want to allow refunds to be issued client side since that could be maliciously done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a service that allows you to process Stripe payments without setting up the server-side yourself: [Noodlio Pay](https://market.mashape.com/noodlio/noodlio-pay-smooth-payments-with-stripe).

You simply send HTTP requests to the API hosted on Mashape.

Here is an example of a request in cURL:

```
curl -X POST --include 'https://noodlio-pay.p.mashape.com/charge/token' 
\ -H 'X-Mashape-Key: <required>' 
\ -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
\ -H 'Accept: application/json' 
\ -d 'amount=100' 
\ -d 'currency=usd' 
\ -d 'description=Purchase with Noodlio Pay' 
\ -d 'source=tok_181ER0E9p71uHfeG90clN2MH' 
\ -d 'stripe_account=acct_12abcDEF34GhIJ5K'
```

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: I have added an example with cURL. I really dont know how to extend the answer further. Perhaps my question was invalid? I asked whether there are such services, and after now a few months found one.